# Book with another planet, thoughts become real and a vampire of sorts

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

There was a book trilogy that had ley lines and thoughts became reality. I want to say it was another planet. The main protagonist was a Count that murdered his family for power/life so ostensibly a vampire.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Our established policy is that we don't close as a duplicate until we have confirmation from OP that the properties are the same, either by acceptance or by comment.

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like C.S. Friedman's [*Coldfire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coldfire_Trilogy) trilogy.

The planet Erna has a psychic field called "the Fae" that can be influenced by people's thoughts, and powerfully by their unconscious fears, which makes the mists a place of nightmare for most people.

> The energy is also sensitive to the human psyche, as the colonists discovered to their dismay. The Fae reacts to human cerebral activity, **bringing to life dreams and manifesting fears**. In fact, many of the first colonists were killed by Fae-constructs, demons and beasts that fed off of their human progenitors, both physically and mentally. It was only by a Great Sacrifice, the loss of all the technology and knowledge the colonists had brought with them, that humanity came to terms with the Fae, at least enough to learn a rudimentary level of control over the power.

The count (I'd probably call him a deuteragonist instead of a protagonist, really) is Gerald Tarant.  Wikipedia describes him:

> The Neocount of Merentha, the Prophet of the Church for Human Unification on Erna. He was a visionary, an individual who sought more adamant uses of the Fae to tame the planet, which was contrary to the Church's primary goal of rendering humans null to the Fae. **He sacrifices his humanity to gain untold control over the Fae by murdering his wife and children in a dark ritual**.

Comment: That was my guess on seeing the question title as well. If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214431/sci-fi-fantasy-book-people-stranded-on-a-planet-where-tech-doesnt-work-magic/214432#214432