Book series where the main character has to murder his own family to control the magic on a newly discovered world
This is an older fantasy series, I read it a long time ago and for the life of me can't remember the title.
The magic system is a mist that can create anything from the thoughts of the people in it. The main character is both good and evil and sacrifices his own family as a way to make the magic harder to access. After doing this, he needs to feed off fear to survive. In the end, he is able to make it so the magic only works for someone willing to sacrifice their own life.

In roughly which year did you read this? Also, do you recall how many books there were in the series?

I read it years ago, maybe in the 80's. Don't remember how many books. The cover art was memorable. A man with long hair and colorful clothing standing in the fork of a dead tree with mist rolling past.

Your question has been closed as a Duplicate in the system. This is not a censure, but more of a bookkeeping policy when it comes to story-identification questions so that questions with the same accepted answer are linked together in the system. You will still receive points for upvotes and people can't comment. The only real change for you is that no new answers can be posted. Congrats on finding it! I rather enjoyed this series.

This is likely C.S. Friedman's The Coldfire Trilogy, specifically Gerald Tarrant.


However, unlike Earth, the entire surface of Erna is wrapped in a powerful energy field known as "the Fae"--a type of energy that comes up to the surface from the core of the planet via a plethora of volcanoes and earthquakes which rock the planet's surface. This is an energy that the native animals of Erna sense and utilize to help them survive (i.e. the Fae is often able to tell a Sensitive individual when an earthquake is coming or if the tides are about to shift). Similar to the Earth's magnetic field, C.S. Friedman explains how if magic existed, it would be a natural force governed by consistent rules. "Like fire, it should be useful when controlled, dangerous if uncontrolled," she says.
The energy is also sensitive to the human psyche, as the colonists discovered to their dismay. The Fae reacts to human cerebral activity, bringing to life dreams and manifesting fears. In fact, many of the first colonists were killed by Fae-constructs, demons and beasts that fed off of their human progenitors, both physically and mentally. It was only by a Great Sacrifice, the loss of all the technology and knowledge the colonists had brought with them, that humanity came to terms with the Fae, at least enough to learn a rudimentary level of control over the power.

....

Gerald Tarrant
The Neocount of Merentha, the Prophet of the Church for Human Unification on Erna. He was a visionary, an individual who sought more adamant uses of the Fae to tame the planet, which was contrary to the Church's primary goal of rendering humans null to the Fae. He sacrifices his humanity to gain untold control over the Fae by murdering his wife and children in a dark ritual. Thus was born the Hunter.


If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214431/sci-fi-fantasy-book-people-stranded-on-a-planet-where-tech-doesnt-work-magic?noredirect=1&lq=1

@DavidW: Sorry... not the first time I beat you by a small amount of time on this question. :-P
